# ProgressBar in Xcode - Hide shadow around

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm using `Progress Bar` in my `Header View` in Xcode with trailing and leading set.
The bar has a black shadow around (left, right) that I would like to hide.

tried this, but didnt work.

```
@IBOutlet weak var progressBar: ProgressView!
progressBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
```

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTYk0.png)

Comment: Could you show the settings of `progressBar` in the Attributes Inspector in the corresponding XIB/Storyboard file?

Comment: I think the view contains the ``ProgressView`` has shadow not the ``ProgressView`` itself